# Uploaded dynamic file cannot be found

Tags: django, django-models

I uploaded a dynamic picture named "IMG_4606.png" through admin page and when loading it through another app, it is not being found.

setting.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project_headshots')
MEDIA_URL = '/project_headshots/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`
```

models.py

```
 from django.db import models
        class Project(models.Model):
            title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
            description = models.TextField()
            technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
            image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="iad")
```

`
html code

```
 img class="card-img-top" src="{{project.image.url}}" alt=""
```

ERROR:

```
 `Not Found: /projects/project_headshots/iad/IMG_4606.png
 [25/Sep/2019 16:28:34] 
 "GET /projects/project_headshots/iad/IMG_4606.png HTTP/1.1" 404'
```

Comment: did you add `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in urls.py? Docs: [Serving files uploaded by a user during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: same error message, this is for something that is uploaded through the admin page, not a static image